# This Waters or These Waters?

Tags: grammatical-number

Suppose, I have to say watching a part of a river to somebody: Hey! Don't swim there. That waters must be deep.

So, which one will be correct: that waters/those waters?

Thank you.

Comment: 'The water must be deep there' is what most native speakers would say.

Answer (score 1):

It's either "that water" or "those waters". "That" is singular, "those" is plural; and "waters" is also plural.

As explained in [this web column](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/this-that-these-those):

> *This* and *that* are singular. *These* and *those* are plural.